# How to update the same time

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, laravel

This is my second update about the same question!

I need to update the app angularjs at the same time in THE TWO CLIENTS

I send my code

First , my html view is this

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div ng-class="{'has-error':myForm.name.$invalid,'has-success':myForm.name.$valida}">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="node.name" required>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="myForm.name.$dirty" >
        <p class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required">Campo obligatorio</p>
    </div>
  <label>Notes</label>
  <textarea name="notes" ng-model="node.notes"></textarea>

  <input type="hidden" name="parent" ng-model="node.parent" ng-init="node.parent=parentId">

  <br>
  <a href="#/" class="btn">Cancel</a>
  <button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
          class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

and a easy table

```
<table class="zebra" style="btn-primary" ng-show="(nodes | filter:search).length > 0">
  <thead>
  <tr class="cabeza" style="background-color:#CEECF5;" >
    <th></th>
    <th><a href="" ng-click="changeSorting('name')"  >name</a></th>
    <th><a href="" ng-click="changeSorting('path')">Path</a></th>
    <th>Operaciones</th>

  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <tr ng-repeat="node in nodes | filter:search | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="node.done" ></td>
    <td>{{node.name}}</td>
    <td>{{node.path}}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#/new/{{node.id}}" class="btn btn-success">Añadir</a>
      <a href="#/edit/{{node.id}}" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="eliminar(node.id)">delete</button>   </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

At my app.js application I have this

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope,$http,$routeParams,$timeout,$location, $filter,Node, User) {
$scope.save = function() {
      $http.post('crear').success(function(data) 
        {
                $timeout(function() {
                $location.path('nodes');
                 $scope.$apply();
                });
        });


  };

  $scope.nodes = Node.query();
})
```

My controller are first at the routes.php

```
Route::post("crear", function()
{

   //
        $input = Input::all();

        $node = Nodes::create($input);

        return Response::json($node);

});
```

And my factory to get a information

```
nodeServices.factory('Node', ['$resource',
  function($resource){

    return $resource('api/nodes/:nodeId', {}, {
     'get': {method:'GET'}
    });
  }]);
```

My problem is that I don't know what information I have to find to continue developing my project

Comment: What do you mean by "show te content"? What content? Sent or received from server? How you want to show?

Comment: I received a content in the same page , jut now http://img110.xooimage.com/files/b/b/9/backend-48c0090.png

Comment: I update the new questoin

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use relative paths, you'd just exclude the domain name:

```
$http.post('/copiaAngus/public/crear').....
```

And really, with laravel you shouldn't need to specify the path to the public folder unless the webroot for your server isn't pointed to the public folder itself. It should look like this:

```
$http.post('/crear').....
```

If you haven't already, you may want to read through the documentation for [angular's http object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: Thanks for all ! You know anything about my second question ? I don't know how to update the two "clients" at the same time. :(

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question before I or anyone else can answer. What information are you wanting to update client records with? What does your database containing the clients look like? What does your laravel controller that is doing the update look like? Without details like those no one can suggest a solution. And as much as you can post the code. A description helps, but seeing the code makes a big difference.